# If it's ''not your cup of tea'' it's not your cup of tea(idioms usage if can be adjusted)

Tags: idioms

I've learned from native speakers that you have to pay close attention to how idioms are constructed, meaning they are fixed and one shouldn't change it especially *articles* and so on.

Furthermore, in my example below, I am not changing it, but rather using it as skillfully as I can, perhaps. Is this correct?

> "I've already challenged my personal values by doing activities that I'm not fond of, and it didn't make me feel good about myself, it was condescending to me actually. **Clearly, if it's not your cup of tea, it's not your cup of tea."**

Do natives also do this?

Comment: You can use idiomatic expressions the way you like, as long as the meaning is clear.

Comment: The sentence is alright. However it sounds a little weird for me. I mean if someone says to me **if it's not your cup of tea, it's not your cup of tea.** I would say "umm, you don't say?" It sounds like a try-to-sound-cool-using-idiom-but-it-doesn't-work sentence

Comment: @Albert, where are from?

Comment: @JohnArvin oh I forgot to mention. I'm not a native

Comment: You are not using the word **condescending** properly. Your use of the "cup of tea" idiom is fine, including the repetition.  *If you don't like it, you don't like it. No use pretending otherwise.*

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo, thx for the correction, got it. Just as I was feeling from my gut that I'm not using ''condescending'' correctly hehe.

Comment: Condescending is one of those words that has moved from having a positive connotation to a negative one. In the 18th century, the King of England might have condescended to speak to my forefather. If that had happened my ancestor would have felt honoured. But now, if the way I speak to someone is considered to be condescending, they will say "who does he think he is, the King of England?"